# How do I remove livereload script from release build?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, livereload

I'm a backend developer messing with a f/e app for a short while and I'm using grunt to watch-livereload my changes.
What is confusing to me is that, to make the livereload work, I have added a script tag to my index.html

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

But I don't really want that script to go into my production, I'm guessing no one want's that either.. how are people dealing with this?
Should I remove the tag from the page manually before I build every time? 
It doesn't look like a great way to go about it, seeing as how grunt is all about automating tasks.. is there a way to automate this task too? 
All I want is to remove the script before publishing for release.

I'm using a simple angular.js app if that matters.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *[grunt-dom-munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger)* to process the index.html on the build grunt task that you use for deployment.

Your script include in *index.html* will look like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js" data-remove="true"></script>
```

and in the grunt file you will have (in the dom_munger section):

```
update: {
            options: {
                remove: ['script[data-remove!="false"]', 'link[data-remove!="false"]']
    }
}
```

This way you will have full control over your index.html before deploying it, just read the docs on don-munger.